# SQL Server Temp Table to a Select Distinct Count Distinct quetsion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok, basically I've got a lot of temp tables I've created and I'm trying to create Validation for the ProvDiff table.

```
DROP TABLE #ProvDiff;

IF OBJECT_ID ('temp.dbo.#ProvDiff') IS NOT NULL 
      DROP TABLE #ProvDiff;

SELECT *
INTO #ProvDiff
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT *
     FROM #finalclaimswithflags f
     WHERE f.[Pay-To Prov NPI] <> f.[Rendering Prov NPI]) ProvDiff;

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT ???) AS 'Unique EI NPIS'
FROM #ProvDiff
```

In my head it seems like the differences should be able to produce a result and I should be able to do a count on that. But for the life of me I can't figure out how to do that. If I do a count on rendering or pay to then those numbers wouldn't necessarily reflect the value for what are above. I know how many of each are produced for above validation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry Ivan, the data is PHI, so I couldn't really show that.

Comment: Sample data does not mean real data from prod DB.

Comment: Understandable, but my system sadly hasn't a test system so mocking up Test data would take a bit of time. :(

Comment: Try to clarify your question then. I have no idea what your intention is, what is supposed to be the right output.

Comment: @J.E.Flint: Time is something people here invest in order to help others, or you in this case, for free. So you might consider investing some time yourself to make it easier and probably just even possible for those volunteers to help you.

Comment: @sticky bit I understand that, that KS for the information this site provides.

Comment: 1). The edit history is still visible, we can still see your original post.  2). There's no sensitive IP in there any way.

Comment: FYI.. If you _really_ think there is some sensitive info you dont want seen..you should mod flag your post for retraction with an explanation. Editing out will still show up the content in revision and deleting doesnt prevent high rep users from seeing it if they have a link

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT *
      FROM #finalclaimswithflags f
      WHERE f.[Pay-To Prov NPI] <> f.[Rendering Prov NPI]
     ) ProvDiff;
```

I don't see why a temporary table would be used for this.

For better or worse, SQL Server does not support `select count(distinct *)`, so you pretty much need a subquery.